# Improper integral of products and ratios of probability density functions

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, integration

I am trying to find out whether the following integral is finite. The integrand consists of product of probability density functions.

$\int \frac{f(x_1,x_2, x_4^*)}{f(x_1^*,x_2, x^*_4)}\frac{f(x_1,x_4, x_2^*)}{f(x_1^*,x_4, x^*_2)}\frac{f(x_2,x_3, x_1^*)}{f(x_2^*,x_3, x^*_1)}\frac{f(x_3,x_4, x_2^*)}{f(x_3^*,x_4, x^*_2)} d\mathbf{x} $

More specifically, f is the pdf of trivariate logistic extreme value distribution. Where,

$f(x_i, x_j, x_k)= (x_ix_jx_k)^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}\exp[-(x_i^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}+x_j^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}+x_k^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}})^\alpha]\{ (x_i^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}+x_j^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}+x_k^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}})^{3(\alpha-1)} - \frac{3(\alpha-1)}{\alpha}(x_i^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}+x_j^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}+x_k^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}})^{2\alpha-3}+ \frac{(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{\alpha^2}(x_i^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}+x_j^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}+x_k^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}})^{\alpha-3}\}$

$f(x_i) = x^{-2} \exp(-x^{-1})$

$ 0 < x_i$ for all i and $\alpha$ is between 0 and 1.

$x_i^*$ are just some fixed arbitrary value between 0 and $\infty$. Also $x_i^* = x_j^*$ for all i and j.

I am at lost trying to find ways to bound the functions so I can show whether the integral converges/diverges or if there are specific conditions that will result in convergence. 
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: For the record, at time of writing this question has attracted a vote to close as "unclear what you're asking". I strongly disagree with this reason given